# Book Didactic Security Notions

Tags: encryption

I want study more about cryptography reading papers, but I have a problems to understand few concepts: security notions, random oracle model, IND-CCA, ... etc. I began study this concepts by internet: wikipedia, sites etc, but I like have a **didactic** book to learn this concepts. Please anybody will be able to recommend a didactic book?

Comment: Asking for references, especially with this broad a scope, seems off-topic to me. See the [FAQ](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practical Cryptography, by Ferguson and Schneier, is slightly more engaging than a pure reference book, and you might find it more readable than some of the other more technical tomes.  Otherwise, there are not many straight-up "story books" that discuss the technology at a bits-and-bytes level.

You will likely find more interesting books in the history category, especially those that discuss wartime codes and cyphers.  "The Code Book" by Simon Singh, is a more technical history than most, and is not a bad read.  "The Story of Magic: Memoirs of an American Cryptologic Pioneer" by Frank Rowlett, is a first hand account of setting up the United States' code breaking capabilities - it's dry, common in the style of the era, but it's obviously very personal.  "Between Silk and Cyanide: A Codemaker's War, 1941-1945", by Leo Marks, is an extremely well-written story, and he brings in a lot of excitement and adventure.  Mr. Marks went on to become a successful screenwriter, and has a gift for telling the stories in a very colorful and engaging way.

While the history books are not overly technical, they still present many of the concepts you seem to be asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Cryptography Theory and Practice is what i would suggest , it finely balances theory and practice as title suggests and all the theory concepts are well explained in normal language with ample references